# Xslt recursive function that return linked tree

Tags: xslt

This is a XSLT code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="*[parent::*]">
  <xsl:param name="pPath"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$pPath"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vValue" select="normalize-space(text()[1])"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$vValue"/>
  <br/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
    <xsl:with-param name="pPath" select="concat($pPath, $vValue, ': ')"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

when appliedon this XML:

```
<ItemSet>
<Item>1
 <iteml1>1.1</iteml1>
 <iteml1>1.2</iteml1>
</Item>
<Item>2
  <iteml1>2.1
    <iteml2>2.1.1</iteml2>
   </iteml1>
</Item>
</ItemSet>
```

the result is :

```
1
1: 1.1
1: 1.2
2
2: 2.1
2: 2.1: 2.1.1
```

what should i add to it so i can have a link on every elemet of that tree as example :

```
<a href="1">1</a>
<a href="1">1</a> : <a href="1/1.1">1.1</a>
<a href="1">1</a> : <a href="1/1.2">1.2</a>
<a href="2">2</a>
<a href="2">2</a> : <a href="2/2.1">2.1</a>
<a href="2">2</a> : <a href="2/2.1">2.1</a> : <a href="2/2.1/2.1.1">2.1.1</a>
```

etc...

Comment: Are you still searching for an answer?

Comment: You want as output a **simil** anchor HTML tag, which is not HTML at all. Is that wanted or typo? Please edit if I'm correct.

Comment: Still need an answer yes, i know that the  <a-href> aint HTML but its because i cant add a link in the example that is why./.. so if u have an answer..share it with us

Comment: I think this can't be accomplished with one single recursive template only. You might need at least a starting template for the `Item`. Is this ok for you?

Comment: I've also edited the wanted output, is that ok? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="*[parent::*]">
                <xsl:param name="pPath"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$pPath"/>
                <xsl:variable name="vValue" select="normalize-space(text()[1])"/>
                <a href="{$vValue}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$vValue"/>
                </a>
                <br/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pPath" select="concat($pPath, $vValue, ': ')"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or try this one

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="html"/>
        <xsl:template match="ItemSet/Item">
        <xsl:variable name="vValue" select="normalize-space(text()[1])"/>
                <a href="{$vValue}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$vValue"/>
                </a>
                <br/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="iteml1 | iteml2">
                <xsl:variable name="vValue" select="normalize-space(text()[1])"/>
                <xsl:variable name="vValueparent" select="normalize-space(../text()[1])"/>

                <a href="{$vValueparent}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$vValueparent"/>
                </a> :
                <a href="{$vValue}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$vValue"/>
                </a><br/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </xsl:template>        
</xsl:stylesheet>
```